# A single question for configuring editors to do LaTeX/Biber compilation?

Tags: discussion, questions

We have various questions from people wanting to set up their editor(s) for use with Biber, or struggling to get the LaTeX/Biber/LaTeX workflow to work: see for example [Biblatex, Biber, and LaTeX: citations undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153647/biblatex-biber-and-latex-citations-undefined). This is mainly because most editors come pre-set for LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX or leave this entirely to the user. I wonder if we should look to create a 'definitive' question to cover this. What I'm imagining is a question with appropriate text to be easy to find, plus instructions for answers (similar to [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)). Each answer would then be specific instructions for an editor (proably with platform variations if appropriate)_, with the idea being that the question itself (and thus the answers) would be community wiki.

Does this sound like a reasonable idea?

---

Bonus question now the main part has been agreed: does it make sense to dupe older editor-specific questions to the new generic one, provided the appropriate editor is now covered by the general question?

Comment: Good idea!  The Biber setup in AUCTeX has been already outlined in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129237/31416).

Comment: @giordano Yes, we have several partial answers, covering one editor in more or less detail. I'm thinking that a single place for the info would help newer users, particularly if they've not got a definite editor preference.

Comment: this would be great. I remember biting my keyboard for TC 2 alpha setting

Comment: It might not hurt to include in the question itself (a gentle reminder about) how the actual LaTeX-BibTeX/Biber-LaTeX sequence is supposed to work, then each answer explains how to set up the editors.  This way people can redirect the posters who seem to be confused about both workflow and/or editor setup to a comprehensive question-and-answer.  (I mean 'seem' because, often enough, the poster does not provide enough information for it to be clear what he or she is having trouble with.)

Comment: For WinEdt, it is sufficient to download and install LaTeXify menu modifier from http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/LaTeXify.php .

Comment: For Texmaker, instructions are here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44095/8569

Comment: @jon Does the text I've put in my model question (as an answer here) cover it or is more needed?

Comment: That's precisely what I was thinking: nice and clear, and (bonus) with a link to a question with a great answer about the LaTeX-BibTeX/Biber-LaTeX(-LaTeX) compilation order.  I'd say the question itself seems more or less ready to post as is.

Comment: @matth Would you add that info to the question I've now asked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: @JosephWright Looks like HarishKumar was faster: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on votes on the question and comments here it seems the answer is 'yes'. Before posting a question on the main site and starting to populate it with answers, it would be a good idea to draft out the question and guideline-comments here: see below.

---

**Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations** [Proposed question title]

Running the minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{example,
  author  = {Other, Anthony Norman},
  title   = {Some things I did},
  year    = {2014},
  journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello\cite{example}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get the warning `There were undefined references`.

I have read [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number) and know that I need to run:

1. LaTeX
2. Biber
3. LaTeX

However, my editor is only set up to run BibTeX. How do I go about setting up my editor/IDE to be able to run Biber, and how do I run the LaTeX/Biber/LaTeX cycle?

---

Comments/guidelines:

- Each answer should be for one editor. If the editor is cross-platform, if possible give a single answer with notes covering the minor platform variations.
- Each answer should be 'stand alone', *i.e.* don't say 'It's almost the same as editor Y but ...'
- Instructions on how to set up build tool such as `arara` or `latexmk` are welcome, but the primary focus should be on the basic 'by hand' approach.

Comment: Question posted as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations